# Why does `vertical-align` property NOT work for <a> with `display:table-cell`?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, displaytag, css-tables

**[JSFiddle SSCCE here](http://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/6tLzc3xv/11/)**

From [this website](https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/):

> Unlike images, table cells default to middle vertical alignment:

From the [text of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445373/when-does-vertical-align-works-in-table-cell-and-when-doesnt),

> Theoretically, vertical-align supposed to work inside an element with
>   display:table-cell. It always works if you add a wrapper with
>   display:table around. But when it has no wrapper, sometimes it will
>   work and sometimes vertical-align will be completely ignored...

**In this SSCCE, `a.previous-slide-arrow` and `a.next-slide-arrow` have `display: table-cell;` and they have a wrapper `first-viewport` with `display:table;`, But still `vertical-align` does not seem to work on `a.previous-slide-arrow` and `a.next-slide-arrow`. Why? And what should I do to make it work?**

---

***Code:***

```css
.image-slideshow-container {
}

.image-slideshow-container img {
 position: fixed;
 display: none;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

img.slider-image1 {
 display: block;
}

.first-viewport {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 display: table;
}

a.previous-slide-arrow, a.next-slide-arrow {
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative;
 
 color: transparent;
    
 opacity: 0.7;
 text-align: center; /* =s */
 left: 20px;
 background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-left-128.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

a.next-slide-arrow {
 right: 20px;
 left: auto;
 background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-right-128.png");
}

.navigation-arrows-container a.previous-slide-arrow:hover,
.navigation-arrows-container a.next-slide-arrow:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}

.navigation-bullets-container {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 60px;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 position: relative;
}

.navigation-bullets-container span {
 display: none;
}

.navigation-bullets-container a {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 5px;
 background: #4b4040;
}

.navigation-bullets-container a:hover{
 background: black;
}

.navigation-bullets-container a.active {
 background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-slideshow-container">
    <img class="slider-image1" src="http://i992.photobucket.com/albums/af42/webtreatsetc/Textures%20Patterns%20Brushes%20from%20Webtreats/LightBlur.png" alt="pitcher!"/>
    <img class="slider-image2" src="http://m.rgbimg.com/cache1vNdB6/users/x/xy/xymonau/600/ooNRizq.jpg" alt="pitcher!"/>
    <img class="slider-image3" src="http://cdn.desktopwallpapers4.me/media/thumbs_400x250/3/23394.jpg" alt="pitcher!"/>
    <img class="slider-image4" src="http://papers.co/wallpaper/papers.co-sd19-sand-storm-gradient-blur-8-wallpaper.jpg" alt="pitcher!"/>
    <img class="slider-image5" src="http://m.rgbimg.com/cache1sw4YI/users/x/xy/xymonau/600/nxXqi9O.jpg" alt="pitcher!"/>
    <img class="slider-image6" src="http://previews.123rf.com/images/hospitalera/hospitalera0805/hospitalera080500016/3089997-Halftone-blue-pattern-with-little-dots-and-some-zoom-blur-applied--Stock-Photo.jpg" alt="pitcher!"/>
</div>


<div class="first-viewport"> 

 <a class="previous-slide-arrow" href="#">&lt;</a>
    
 <div class="navigation-bullets-container">
  <a class="navigation-bullet1" href="javascript: changeImage(1)" > 
            <span>Bullet</span>
        </a>
        <a class="navigation-bullet2" href="javascript: changeImage(1)" > 
            <span>Bullet</span>
        </a>
        <a class="navigation-bullet3" href="javascript: changeImage(1)" > 
            <span>Bullet</span>
        </a>
        <a class="navigation-bullet4" href="javascript: changeImage(1)" > 
            <span>Bullet</span>
        </a>
        <a class="navigation-bullet5" href="javascript: changeImage(1)" > 
            <span>Bullet</span>
        </a>
        <a class="navigation-bullet6" href="javascript: changeImage(1)" > 
            <span>Bullet</span>
        </a>
 </div>
    
 <a class="next-slide-arrow" href="#">&gt;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Set `background-position: center;` to vertical align the background image. The solution above only work with the content inside the element, not work with `background-image` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 issues :

### Height

Your `first-viewport` has a height of 100%. When you work with % heights, know that the parent must have a height to so the % height of the children can be calculated.

In this case, you have to add `html, body {height: 100%;}`, which are the parents of `first-viewport`. (Honestly, it's not mandatory but you should do it as your div could have a zero height on some browsers.)

### Background

Now, your `<a>` tags are actually taking the full height and **are** centered vertically, but you feel the opposite because of your background.

[image: Blue zone is your a tag real position.]

Now what you have to do is fixing your background position (since you're using the background property to display arrows).

```
a.previous-slide-arrow, a.next-slide-arrow {
    background-position: center;
}
```

This simple line above should fix it.

Comment: Thank you so very much for the elaborate answer. I greatly appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

**If you want listen click event only on the arrow :**
You must wrap your `<a>` element in div with `display: table-cell`.
And your `<a>` contain only your background arrow.

**Alternatively:**
Or you can apply a `background-position: 50% 50%` to center your background arrow in your element.

Comment: Yeah, in this instance centering the background will do the trick. `vertical-align` has no bearing on the position of the background.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do intend to listen click event on the arrow, let me test it.